# Was the Star Trek episode Catspaw originally intended as a Halloween episode or was it just coincidence?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-the-original-series

Was the Star Trek episode **Catspaw** originally intended as a Halloween episode or was it just coincidence?

Did Gene Rodenberry or network executives specifically request an episode be written with scary elements to show during Halloween?

Or was there a story that a writer had submitted that had some scary Halloween related elements that they ended up showing during Halloween?

Comment: Wikipedia says the episode was delayed to coincide with Halloween, but offers no references and there's no indication that beyond rescheduling that it was deliberately planned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Or was there a story that a writer had submitted that had some scary Halloween related elements that they ended up showing during Halloween?

## Mostly..but the timing was deliberate.

Information can be found in [*These Are The Voyages: Season Two*](http://www.thesearethevoyagesbooks.com/buy-season-two.html) by Marc Daniels..

In there he quotes the writer, Robert Bloch..

> **“They wanted a Halloween story,”** Bloch told Starlog magazine in 1986. “I wanted to do something that would involve changes in appearances. So, I decided that instead of having the usual Jekyll-and-Hyde transformation, I’ll have a female who was capable of chameleon-like adaptations. And the rest just fell into place.”

and further...

> “Catspaw” aired four days before Halloween, 1967. Talking to this author [Daniels], Dorothy Fontana said, **“That was planned all along to be like a Halloween show.** When Bob [Bloch] pitched it, we said, **‘That’s got to be the Halloween show for sure!’** I liked it. I thought it was pretty good.”

So basically, it was pitched as a **scary story** and the producers & other writers grabbed it and made it a Halloween show.

Comment: Thanks. I've been wondering about this for a while. I had read that it was delayed to coincide with Halloween which seemed to indicate that it **wasn't** planned out much.